# Overcoming palmitic acid intolerance

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry

What can stop the body from being able to process or break down palmitic acid?  The acid stays in the stomach and burns causing a similar reaction as heart burn when the volume is high.  Heart burn medication makes the issue worse. In smaller doses it causes the esophagus to swell causing a asthma type reaction and wheezing when breathing through the mouth but leaves the nasal passages unaffected.  The symptoms appear several hours after consumption.  The reactions have been noted in any food containing the acid natural or additive usually in the form of palm or peanut oil.  Once such natural example is a Pizza with Mushrooms, several hours after eating nausea will occur along with the burning sensation.  Expelling of the contents reveals acidic liquid and the mushrooms only.

Is there any recourse for neutralizing the acid safely or supplementing the body with the missing function to process the acid.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. In particular, **I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the primary aim seems to be medical treatment (rather than biological understanding).** This may be appropriate for [MedicalSciences.SE], but please read that site's help before reposting. Thanks! 

Comment: There is a proposed edit by an "anonymous user" — was that you? If you are having trouble making an [edit] please register and, if necessary, consult this information on [merging accounts](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to gain access to your post ...